# pandas read_htm parse fails for lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lxml

I definitely have lxml installed but pandas read_html thinks not. (I am on windows10 python38).
my code:

```
# problem: lxml not found, please install it
import pandas as pd
import lxml            # IS installed
url = 'https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Yvonne'            
df = pd.read_html(url)  # lxml not found, please install it
print(df.head())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Python/Python38/OurStuff/AI/NLP/knowledge-scraper.py", line 5, in 
> pd = pd.read_html(url)  # lxml not found, please install it
> File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1098, in read_html
> return _parse(
> File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 902, in _parse
> parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
> File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 859, in _parser_dispatch
> raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
> ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try installing it again~ `pip install lxml` You can also try running it with `pd.read_html(url, flavor='html5lib')` instead.

Comment: Some side issues: 1) `pd.read_html()` returns a *list* of DataFrames, not a DataFrame. 2) There are no html tables on that webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestions. I was having trouble using bs4 and selenium and thought this might provide an alternative., but I still can't get it to work.